# BVH Export/Import, Armature different when re-imported

Tags: animation, export, armature, import

If I export an armature as bvh and then import it back, the imported armature doesn't look anything like the original.

Could anyone please have a look and advise?, [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/20pno7txud5ae8o/untitled.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Is the animation correct?

Comment: @ideasman42 what do you mean? this file is just an example. My original file has different animation but have the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BVH format stores bones differently to Blender.

Specifically, it doesn't support bone-length and bone-roll, each bone is just a joint
*(as if you have many parented empties in Blender),* so this information is lost on export, when the BVH is imported back in, the animation will match the original, but not the armature.

The bone lengths & roll have to be calculated on import (because its not in the file).

This is simply a limitation of the BVH format, or a difference at least, with Blender's armature representation.