# Import a .mhx file and export it to .bvh problem

Tags: animation, makehuman

I imported a .mhx file. After that, I export it to .bvh without changing it. I remark that when I import the .bvh file, I did not get the same .mhx file? I found a closer question to this problem [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/import-a-bvh-file-and-export-it-to-be-the-same) but i did not understand how can resolve this problem. Are there any configuration before exporting to .bvh or before importing it? Any suggestion?
[image]

Comment: When you export from Makehuman try to change axes to Z up and Y forward.

Comment: @Denis, when I export from Makehuman as .mhx there is no option to change axes. I can change axes just if I import as *.dae

Comment: @Denis I think the problem is come from blender because when I import .mhx I did not get any problem. The problem is presented just when I export to .bvh

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer to this is just to save your work as a blender file, i.e. .blend.

I could not find a better way of getting around importing a .mhx file, and then .bvh file and saving my work, so I can reload it later?

As was explained here [BVH Export/Import, Armature different when re-imported](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27779/bvh-export-import-armature-different-when-re-imported) , blender files encode more information than bvh files so it make sense to save in blender format.